# Make flex items wrap two at a time

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

What I have now is when the window re-sizes, the boxes adjust accordingly to fit the width. However, what I want is to have a minimum of two boxes move to the next line instead of 3 on top and 1.

Is this achievable with flexbox and if not, how would I accomplish this?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/cqdwLyxu/

```css
.line{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom:30px;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  
}
body,html{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:relative;
}
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.box{
  width:200px;
  min-width:200px;
  background:blue;
  margin:0 10px 0 10px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="line">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Solely with flexbox? No...it's not...but then  it's not possible with any other layout method either. Media queries would be required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a media query that changes the `flex-basis` to 50% on wrap, forcing two items per line.

Add this to your CSS:

```
@media ( max-width: 800px ) {
    .box {
           flex-basis: calc(50% - 20px);
           margin: 10px; 
         }
}
```

[**Revised Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/cqdwLyxu/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me arrive at another method but it's not flexbox related...what does the flex-basis calc do?  For me, the fiddle does go to two by two on re-size but it still does 3-1 for a little before that, at last for me.

Comment: [**`flex-basis`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) sets the initial length of the flex item. In this case it would be the width.

Comment: [**`calc`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) makes the value a calculation. Here it's saying: Make the `flex-basis` a width of 50% minus the left and right margin size. (Otherwise the total width would exceed 100%).

Comment: You can adjust the `max-width: 800px` so the 2x2 breakpoint occurs on wider or narrower screen size. It's still doing 3-1 for you because the wrapping is occurring before the media query executes. So try `max-width: 1200px`. https://jsfiddle.net/cqdwLyxu/2/

Comment: The second demo from comments is better than the `Revised Demo`, there is a flaw and it displays 3 columns briefly.